# Trying to use Apache Camel with Spring

Tags: spring, apache-camel, spring-camel, smooks

I am currently learning to use Apache Camel. To serve my needs I am trying a project I downloaded from the internet but the whole thing seemed to be stuck on an error that I can't debug. It's been a week, I would appreciate if anybody could explain to me what is going wrong or give me a lead in a specific direction. Thank you all.

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

    <camelContext id="camelContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route>
            <from uri="file://${input.dir}?fileName=input-message.csv"/>
            <log message="Before SmooksComponent  ${body}"/>
            <to uri="smooks://smooks-config.xml"/>
            <log message="After SmooksComponent  ${body}"/>
        </route>
    </camelContext>

</beans>
```

```
private static final String camelConfig = "META-INF/spring/camel-context.xml";

public static void main(String... args) throws Exception
{
    CamelContext camelContext = configureAndStartCamel(camelConfig);
    // Give Camel time to process the file.
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    camelContext.stop();
    printEndMessage();
}
```

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring] Offending resource: class path resource [META-INF/spring/camel-context.xml]

at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:72)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:119)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:111)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:281)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1388)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1371)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:179)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:149)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:96)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:511)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:338)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:224)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:195)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:257)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:128)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:94)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:671)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
at org.smooks.examples.camel.csv2xml.Main.configureAndStartCamel(Main.java:87)
at org.smooks.examples.camel.csv2xml.Main.main(Main.java:64)
```

Comment: you need to have  xml ns for camel looks like.

Comment: as a side note, Ifind that the Red Hat BOM files (https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/org/jboss/redhat-fuse/fuse-springboot-bom/) are very useful.  These contain version aligned projects that work together.

Answer (score 1):

For anybody who might encounter the situation kindly note the imports were incomplete.

I did not import the camel-spring of course which should be same version as camel-core.

Regards all.

Comment: Which imports were incomplete? I see camel-spring in your camel-context.xml. I'm asking because I'm having the same problem.